# SSOAP gives errors when making requests

Tags: xml, r, soap

I'm trying to connect to my local gov't statistics web service, but keep getting errors.

```
# install.packages("SSOAP", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source")
library(SSOAP)
library(XML)

wsdl <- "http://analitica.spb.ru/UniversalWSAnalitica-war/UniversalWSAnaliticaService?wsdl"
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(wsdl)

def <- processWSDL(doc)
iac_iface <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def)
```

Then, `iac_iface@functions$getTerrTree()` gives me

> Argument "parameters" is missing with no default

And `iac_iface@functions$getIndTree(dateActual = "24.06.2014 11:00:00", treeLVL = 1)` gives

> unused arguments (dateActual = "24.06.2014 11:00:00", treeLVL = 1)

While raw XML requests, for example, work:

```
library(httr)
xml.request  <- 
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.universal.department14.iac.spb.ru/\">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:getIndTree>
         <dateActual>24.06.2013 11:00:00</dateActual>
         <treeLVL>1</treeLVL>
      </ws:getIndTree>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
r <- POST("http://analitica.spb.ru/UniversalWSAnalitica-war/UniversalWSAnaliticaService", body = xml.request)
stop_for_status(r)
content(r)
```

I tried Python library suds, also works perfectly. Can somebody please tell what's wrong with SSOAP use?
R version 3.1.2 on 32-bit Debian Testing.